# sql query default in oracle

Tags: sql, default

```
create table dvds(
   dvdid number not null primary key,
   dvdname varchar(60) not null,
   numdisks number not null default 1,
   yearrlsd date not null,
   mtypeid varchar(4) not null,
   stuid varchar(4) not null,
   ratingid varchar(4) not null,
   formid char(2) not null,
   statid char(3) not null,
   foreign key (mtypeid) references movietypes (mtypeid)
)
```

whrn i am running this command in oracle it is giving error:

> missing right parenthesis

but after removing default it is working

Comment: Check out the manual: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/statements_7002.htm#SQLRF54369

Answer (score 2):

The default value should come *before* the constraints (not null);

```
numdisks number default 1 not null,
```

[SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e2735/1).

Comment: +1 . . . I didn't realize that Oracle had this requirement.  Other databases are more flexible.